# Social Sharing Capabilities on Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: html

I cant figure out how to add social sharing icon buttons for facebook, twitter, email on Appcelerator Titanium for my mobile app. I am looking for the icon and the logic. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no inbuilt twitter support with appcelerator, twitter has a very simple API that you can use Ajax calls to use, just place a button with a background image. Here's a link to the API for the Facebook stuff, there's an example of the buttons, login / logout, posting / querying on this page

http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/1.8.2/Titanium.Facebook-module